# Drupal Commerce Export Orders in CSV format

Tags: 7, commerce

How can I export Order details along with custom line item fields data in CSV format?

Comment: You can use Views and Views Export modules. It is kinda straight forward. Views Export provides you with a Export display , you do the filter in the view and in the end it will return you a link where the orders can be downloaded in csv format . Success!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Views and Views Export modules.

Views Export provides you with a Export display, you do the filter in the view and in the end it will return a link where the orders can be downloaded in csv format.